# Center a text between two dynamic spans on the left and right

Tags: html, css, center

I tried to find a way with css and html to style a headline like this:

```
[SPAN variable width ] ------------- Always Center Text -- [     SPAN, variable width     ]
```

- At the **center** must be a Text,
- pinned on the **right** and **left** side must be a *span*.

The problem is, that the **Always Center Text** must be in the middle according to the **variable** width of the right and left element. (they could be smaller or wider)

Note: The --- is a continuous horizontal line as shown in the code between the elements with a small padding at the beginning and end.

Here's what i have got so far:
**https://fiddle.jshell.net/cfmnvjhx/1/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
}
.center-line {
  color: #00BF2D;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.center-line span{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: white;
}
.center-line:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: gray;
}
.label{
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:600px"> <!-- UNCHANGEABLE -->
  <div class="row">
    <div style="float: left;">
      <span class="label label-default">WWWWWIIIIIDEEEEE</span>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;">
      <span class="label label-default">small</span>
    </div>
    <div class="center-line" style="margin: 0 auto">
      <span>Always Center Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @FireEmerald Updated my answer

Comment: Yes, i had to add some stuff here and there for the padding, but now it work's as expected.